# Фильтр массива php

Tags: php

Есть список матчей, выводится из массива. При клике на матч в $_GET запрос уходит ID матча. Мне надо вывести только этот матч, то есть отфильтровать массив, и оставить только один матч.
Сейчас я делаю так, но думаю такой метод не очень хороший

```
if(isset($_GET['match'])) {
    $matches = getMatches();
    foreach ($matches as $match) { 
        if ($match['id'] == $_GET['match']) {
            $currentMatch = $match;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В каком виде изначально хранятся матчи, что происходит в `getMatches()`?

Comment: @Alexxosipov `getMatches()` возвращает массив матчей.

Comment: Мне опыт подсказывает, что Вы совершили архитектурную ошибку. Что стоит до метода `getMatches()`? Откуда берутся эти данные? Почему не вынесли объект матча в отдельный класс?

Comment: Ну и от нас-то вы что хотите? Если есть метод получающий все матчи, значит должен быть метод получающий матч по его ID.

Comment: @u_mulder данные берутся с API, а количество бесплатных запросов ограничено, поэтому делать лишний запрос не вариант

Comment: Ну не делайте, вот вы написали уже код, он работает. Максимум можно `break` добавить чтобы после найденного матча по массиву не ходить.

Comment: @u_mulder то есть в php нет метода который фильтрует массив и возвращает в массив только с данными которые надо? Типа как в JS .filter()

Comment: @Alexxosipov это wordpress и здесь без ООП. Данные берутся с API

Comment: Вам говорят. что существует функция [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) и там есть примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам метод поиска нужного элемента в массиве у вас в принципе обычен. Другой вопрос в том, что если данное действие потенциально будет повторяться, то каждый раз писать подобное - не лучшая затея.

Наиболее простой способ для такого поиска, да и в целом, сделать так, чтобы ключами возвращаемого в `getMatches` массива были `id`, тогда искать ничего и не понадобится.

Модифицируйте вашу функцию `getMatches`

```
function getMatches(){
    .....
    return $result;
}
```

например, как-то так

```
function getMatches(){
   ...... 
   return array_combine(array_column($result,'id'), $result);
}
```

и сможете использовать, условно, так:

```
if(isset($_GET['match'])){
     $matches = getMatches();
     $current = $matches[ $_GET['match'] ] ;
}
```

Второй вариант - определите функцию `getMatchById($id)` или нечто подобное, в которой отфильтруете нужный матч и вернете его.

```
 function getMatchById($id){
     $matches = getMatchs();

     foreach($matches as $m){
          if( $m['id'] == $id) return $m;
     }
     return null;
 }
```